# why is D is a linear transformation and how do I find kernel of D.

Tags: linear-algebra

Define the *differentiation operator D* to be the transformation
D : $C_∞$ (*$R$*)→$C_∞$ (*$R$*) given by D( f ) = $f^{'}$ .

**(1)** How I explain that D is a linear transformation.

**(2)** How can I find the kernel of D. In particular, a basis for
ker(D) and its dimension and is D one-to-one?

Comment: Have you made any progress or have any ideas where you might start?

Comment: No sir, I'm was still pondering how to start but now I'll start from the hints I have so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $D(f+\lambda g)=(f+\lambda g)'=f'+\lambda g'=D(f)+\lambda D(g)$ so $D$ is linear
- $f\in\ker(D)\iff f'=0\iff f=\text{constant}$ so $\ker(D)=\operatorname{span}(x\mapsto 1)$ and $\dim\ker(D)=1$

Comment: Perfect! Now how do I show that $D$ is onto $C_∞$ (**$R$**) and  construct a function $F$ such that $D$($F$) = $f$ for any $f$ in $C_∞$ (**$R$**),

Comment: $D(F)=f\iff F'=f$ so $F$ is an anti derivative of $f$.

Comment: and $D$ is one-to-one isnt? because dim ($D$) =1

Comment: No! Since $\ker D\ne\{0\}$ then $D$ isn't one-to-one.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by  $ker D$ not equal to {${0}$}?

Comment: @maths Actually I just got it thanks :)

Comment: how can I show that every real number $λ$ is an eigenvalue of $D$ by finding a corresponding eigenfunction and what will be the dimension of its eigenspace

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\dfrac{d}{dx}(af(x)+bg(x))= a\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x) + b\dfrac{d}{dx}g(x)$

and

$\dfrac{d}{dx} \;c = 0$